# next-redux-wrapper in getServerSideProps in nextjs

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

I am trying to call one action function in getServerSideProps. I am using typeScript.

Actually, in javascript I use it only this way-

```
import { wrapper } from "Redux/store";
import { getVideo } from "Redux/Actions/videoAction";
//Serversider data fatching
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) =>
    async (context) => {
      await store.dispatch(getVideo());
    }
)
```

But When I am trying to use it in typescript I faced some problems. I can solve some but One is not understanding.

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) =>
    async (context) => {
      await store.dispatch(getNews() as any);
    }
)
```

Here I use `getNews() as any` types. I can't say it is right or wrong!

My main problem is context and async function-

I actually finding this error-
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error clearly explains it: You have to return `Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<any>>`

In your current function you are not returning anything. if you annotate getSerververSideProps:

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps =
  wrapper.getServerSideProps(async (context) => {}
```

if you hover over `GetServerSideProps`, its type definition

```
(alias) type GetServerSideProps<P extends { [key: string]: any; } = { 
  [key: string]: any; }, Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery> =
  (context: GetServerSidePropsContext<Q>) Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<P>>
```

Just add return statement

```
return { props: { id: null } };
```

Comment: I am not understanding what are you say! Can you describe more

Comment: @Jannat You need to add a `return` statement inside your `getServerSideProps` function, i.e. `return { props: { } };`, that can't be omitted.